# Why is field in JOIN query null?

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables in a MySQL (Percona) server:
[image]

What I'm trying to do is find the top albums whose photos have won the most battles.  For each album, I want to display a thumbnail of its featured photo, identified by `album_photo`.`photo`

My query so far is:

```sql
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.name,
    feature.thumb_path,
    SUM(p.wins) wins,
    SUM(p.battles) battles,
    SUM(p.wins) / SUM(p.battles) album_popularity
FROM
    photo p,
    album a,
    album_photo ap
LEFT JOIN photo feature ON ap.photo_id = feature.id AND ap.featured = 1
WHERE p.id = ap.photo_id AND ap.album_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id, feature.thumb_path
ORDER BY album_popularity DESC, SUM(p.battles) DESC
```

This query is returning results in the order I'd expect, but some of the `thumb_path` values are NULL.  *Every* album has a featured photo.  In other words, `album` is one-to-many with `album_photo`, and at least one of those rows in `album_photo` has `featured = 1`

I'm no DBA, so this might be obvious for some of you but... why is this happening?  I feel like I'm 85% of the way there, but I'm missing a `JOIN`, or referencing an already referenced table by a new alias, or a subquery of some sort.  Maybe I have to re-join both `album_photo` and `photo` again?

Any insight would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
After adopting the syntax suggested by Rick James, I got this query:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.name,
    ap.photo_id,
    p.thumb_path,
    SUM(p.wins) wins,
    SUM(p.battles) battles,
    SUM(p.wins) / SUM(p.battles) album_popularity
FROM album a
JOIN album_photo ap ON a.id = ap.album_id
JOIN photo p ON ap.photo_id = p.id
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING SUM(p.battles) > 1
ORDER BY album_popularity DESC, SUM(p.battles) DESC
```

Which is populating all the fields, but is returning the first photo (lowest ID) in the album, not the featured photo.  So I want to somehow link each row in the resultset to the row in `album_photo` that matches each row's `album_id`, then link again back to `photo`.  I tried doing just that with:

```sql
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.name,
    apf.photo_id,
    pf.thumb_path,
    SUM(p.wins) wins,
    SUM(p.battles) battles,
    SUM(p.wins) / SUM(p.battles) album_popularity
FROM  album a
JOIN  album_photo ap ON a.id = ap.album_id
JOIN  photo p ON ap.photo_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN album_photo apf  ON p.id = apf.photo_id AND apf.featured = 1
LEFT JOIN photo pf ON apf.photo_id = pf.id
GROUP BY  a.id
HAVING SUM(p.battles) > 1
ORDER BY album_popularity DESC, SUM(p.battles) DESC
```

This is returning the correct rows, but the photo information is `NULL` except for albums where the featured photo for a given album is also the photo with the lowest `id`.

Answer (score 1):

If the database can't find a matching record in the photo table then there are only two possibilities:

- *Either*: the record really *isn't* there (but you say that there *should* be).
- *Or*: your Join conditions are wrong.

If you are saying that "Every album has a featured photo." (I'm guessing that they *don't*, BTW!) then you can *lose* the LEFT join and use a regular, INNER join.
Actually, I would suggest that you should *always* use "inner join" syntax in your queries - you're currently mixing implicit ("comma-join") and explicit join syntaxes and it's really difficult to see what's going on.

Comment: When I get rid of the `LEFT`, then the resultset returned is entirely different.  Fully populated, but it's returning a different set of rows.

Comment: As I said: that means that either your join conditions are wrong or your data isn't the way you think it is.  Rebuild the query, starting with just two tables and adding more in, one at a time, until the resultset starts to "go wrong", then figure out /why/ it went wrong at that point (dodgy data or join conditions), then "fix" that.  Repeat this process until the query is back up to "full strength".

Answer (score 1):

Use `JOIN`, not `LEFT JOIN`.  `LEFT is useful when the row in the second table may be missing, and you _want_` NULLs`.

Use the modern syntax:

```
FROM a
JOIN b ON b.x = a.y
```

That is, use `ON` for saying how tables are 'related'; use `WHERE` for 'filtering'.

See this for performance guidance on many-to-many table indexing:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Comment: When I get rid of the `LEFT`, then the resultset returned is entirely different.  Fully populated, but it's returning a different set of rows.

Comment: @Quasipickle - A different _set_ of rows?  Or are the rows in a different _order_?  I a particular order is needed, you _must_ add an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: A different set of rows.  My query does have an `ORDER BY` clause.  Thinking about it - I'm just going to redesign my DB a bit so `album` gets a `featured_photo_id` column, rather than recording that info in `album_photo`.  Thanks for your attention nonetheless.

Comment: @Quasipickle - Good.  Previously you had many-to-many, which allowed each album to have many featured_photos.  Now you have many-to-one, which is "logically" the right relationship.